# How to print a statement using ArrayOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, oop, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to print a `System.out.println` statement using `ArrayOutOfBoundException` but I am not quite sure how to go about doing this.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class Ex4
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text= "";

        if ( args.length <= 3 ) { 

            for (int i=0; i<args.length-1; i++) {
                text = text  + args[i];
            }

            System.out.println(text);
        }
        else if( args.length > 3 ) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of Bounds Exc. Size is 4 or more"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to call `System.out.println`, just do so - why would you want to throw an exception instead?

Comment: This question is from one of my exam past papers and it asks to use that exception to print the statement specifically, otherwise i would have done what you have mentioned. thanks

Comment: It seems like a nonsensical question to me. I suggest you bring this up with your tutor (or whoever) to check whether any exams you will be sitting are likely to include such odd things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a `RuntimeException`, which should not really be seen by users, a better solution would be to print directly to `System.err` or use a logging framework like `log4j`:

```
} else if (args.length > 3) {
    System.err.println("Out of Bounds Exc. Size is 4 or more"); 
}
```

However, to answer your original question, to specifically log the AIOOBE, you would need to catch it:

```
try {

} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {
    // log here...
}
```

But, again, catching runtime exceptions is not the way to go here as they are actually meant to represent programming errors and not user input issues